# Replace ' with "

Tags: javascript

The `jQuery.parseJSON(str)` won't parse if the strings do not have `"` around them. But mine has `'`

How can I replace the `'` with `"` for this string

```
{'type': '2', 'name': '321', 'price': 321}
```

I tried with var `str.replace("'", """)` but did not do anything.

Edit: Sorry I wrote with `"` but it was meant as `'`. Changed it.

Comment: Single quotes aren't valid delimiters for JSON. The example you show *does* have double quotes. So I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad copied the wrong one.

Comment: The question should really be: where are you getting broken JSON from?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm getting it from a server with a django (python) framework. I create the dict myself server side with double quotes. But as I pass the dict to client side it's getting changed somehow.

Comment: Then you should look into that, are you just using `str` somewhere rather than actually serialising it as JSON? At the very least, `json.dumps` would do the right thing, but I'd guess Django can handle it somehow.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I could look into it at some point. But for now I think a lone line javascript will suffice :) Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change

```
{'type': '2', 'name': '321', 'price': 321}
```

to

```
{"type": "2", "name": "321", "price": 321}
```

Use:

```js
var text= "{'type': '2', 'name': '321', 'price': 321}";
console.log(text);
text = text.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
str.replace(/"/g, "'");
```

Or

```
str.replace(/"/g, '\'');
```

Comment: i think he meant it the other way round ' instead of "